# How to capture the Notes Data directory specified in notes.ini?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I need to get the value for the Notes data directory.  I need it for a scheduled agent I am going to run.  The program directory and data directory are on separate drives.

I thought the following code would work but I am not getting a return value.

String console = session.sendConsoleCommand(servername, "show config Directory");

//Code runs but the following line does not display anything

System.out.println(" Here is console value: " + console);

There are not any permission or other errors.  What am I missing?

V/R,

Kev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use this obscure construct? Do you need the directory of ANOTHER server?

If you need it from the server where the agent runs then just use

```
String directory = session.getEnvironmentString("Directory", true)
```